# Headless chrome driver redirects all urls from http to https

Tags: selenium, docker, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to run selenium-webdriver tests inside docker container with headless chrome against local app (in another docker container). This local app doesn't support https, only http. But all driver's calls to http are automatically redirected to https.
However on local Mac, with same chromedriver version i don't have such problem

I've tried different docker files, but no luck.

My dockerfile

```
FROM ruby:2.5.5-buster as deps

RUN apt-get update; \
    apt-get install -y \
  ruby-dev \
  chromium \
  xvfb \
  build-essential \
  libpcre3-dev \
  libmariadb-dev \
  postgresql \
  postgresql-contrib \ 
  libxml2-dev \
  libxslt-dev \
  libffi-dev \
  default-libmysqlclient-dev \
  curl \
  unzip \
  wget \
  ruby-nokogiri

# install google chrome
RUN wget https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
RUN apt install -y ./google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb

# install chromedriver
RUN wget -O /tmp/chromedriver.zip http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/`curl -sS chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/LATEST_RELEASE`/chromedriver_linux64.zip
RUN unzip /tmp/chromedriver.zip chromedriver -d /usr/local/bin/

# set display port and dbus env to avoid hanging
ENV DISPLAY=:99
ENV DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=/dev/null
```

What i'm getting inside of container:

```
irb(main):009:0> driver.get("http://app:4000/hotels/los-angeles/yoba")
=> nil
irb(main):010:0> driver.current_url
=> "https://app:4000/hotels/los-angeles/yoba"
```